# Let nginx start if upstream host is unavailable or down

Tags: docker, nginx, error-handling, upstream

I have several docker container running, which are served by a reverse-proxy. For each service there is a subdomain.

Some services I only start when I need them. Thats no problem until the server restarts. Then nginx wont start because the upstream server (docker container) are not running.

One problem to solve this is to use variables as [shown here](https://sandro-keil.de/blog/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/).
Its not very nice as you have to use a Internal Docker DNS resolver IP, which can cause errors. Is here no other "upstream host unavailble" handling for nginx?

Comment: any luck with handling this issue ?